# Change datatype when importing Excel file into Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to import an excel file to access. data types have to be specified before i import them to new temp file every week. trying to improve my transfer spreadsheet VBA code to select specific data types automatically.

Comment: Good to know. Are you going to share your code or hope we can figure it out ourselves? Looks like you're new to the site. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question

Answer (score 2):

Don't import the sheet, but link it. Then create a simpel select query with the linked table as source and where you convert and clean up the data.

Now, use this query for importing to the final table or your further processing.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the info at these two links.

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacimportwbado

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

Post back with specific questions.